# Diffeomorphism and homeomorphism between open ball and polydisc in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, diffeomorphism

Recently I came to know that for $n\geq 2$, the open ball $B(0,1) = \{z\in \mathbb{C}^n: |z|<1\}$ and the polydisc $\Delta(0;1) = \{z\in \mathbb{C}^n: |z_j|<1, j=1,\ldots, n\}$ are not biholomorphic.

This made me wonder whether $B(0,1) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x||<1\}$ and the polydisc $\Delta(0;1) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: |x_j|<1, j=1,\ldots, n\}$ are diffeomorphic?

I know that the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equivalent to the metric topology, i.e. topology generated by open polydiscs is same as the one generated by open balls. Does this imply that $B(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\Delta(0;1)$?

Comment: @Dap Wouldn't it be worth to write an official answer even it is just a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equivalent to the metric topology, i.e. topology generated by open polydiscs is same as the one generated by open balls. Does this imply that $B(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\Delta(0;1)$?

Not if it's for a topological reason. For example, the topology on $\mathbb R^n$ is also generated by the sets which are unions of two open balls of radius $r$ and whose centers are at distance $5r$. But a disjoint union $B(0, 1) \sqcup B(0, 1)$ is definitely not homeomorphic to $B(0, 1)$.

- We have a smooth map
  $$\begin{align*}
  B(0, 1) & \to \mathbb R^n \\
  x & \mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt{1- \|x\|^2}}
  \end{align*}$$
  with smooth inverse
  $$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb R^n & \to B(0, 1) \\
  y & \mapsto \frac{y}{\sqrt{1 + \|y\|^2}}
  \end{align*}$$
- If $g : (-1, 1) \to \mathbb R$ is any diffeomorphism, then
  $$\begin{align*}
  \Delta(0, 1) & \to \mathbb R^n \\
  (x_1, \ldots, x_n) & \mapsto (g(x_1), \ldots, g(x_n))
  \end{align*}$$
  is a smooth map with smooth inverse
  $$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb R^n & \to \Delta(0, 1) \\
  (y_1, \ldots, y_n) & \mapsto (g^{-1}(y_1), \ldots, g^{-1}(y_n))
  \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

They are diffeomorphic since they are both open star shaped sets, see  [A star shaped open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184453/a-star-shaped-open-set-in-mathbbrn-is-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbrn)

Comment: How to prove that a polydisc is star-shaped? I expected that there will be a direct proof of diffeomorphism; similar to the proof of [open ball being diffeomorphic to Euclidean space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1025308/214604). Also, with my present knowledge level, I couldn't understand the proof given in the link. I will be grateful if you could also give a brief outline of the proof.

Comment: @rationalbeing: it's star shaped at zero because $z\in \Delta(0;1)$ implies $\lambda z\in\Delta(0,1)$ for $\lambda\in[0,1].$ The answer by "40 votes" is quite conceptual and just relies on an intuitive fact about ODEs.

Comment: And yes there is probably a much simpler proof for this case

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed show that two balls for two (equivalent) norms are homeomorphic :

[Homeomorphism between open unit balls from equivalent distances](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713859/homeomorphism-between-open-unit-balls-from-equivalent-distances)